# linux get_random_bytes error: implicit declaration of function

Tags: linux-device-driver

I have to make a device driver for a Yahtzee program that returns a random number 1-6.  I am very new to Linux and am really not comfortable with programming in it.  I keep getting an erro for the get_random_bytes function.  It says, error: implicit declaration of function ‘get_random_bytes’  Here is my code so far:

```
    static ssize_t dice_driver_read(struct file * file, char * buf,
                      size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
     {

    unsigned char i;
    int len = 1;
    get_random_bytes(&i, sizeof(char));

   // char *dice_driver_str = "Hello, world!\n";
   // int len = strlen(dice_driver_str); /* Don't include the null byte. */
    /*
     * We only support reading the whole string at once.
     */
if (count < len){
            return -EINVAL;}
    /*
     * If file position is non-zero, then assume the string has
     * been read and indicate there is no more data to be read.
     */
if (*ppos != 0){
            return 0;}
    /*
     * Besides copying the string to the user provided buffer,
     * this function also checks that the user has permission to
     * write to the buffer, that it is mapped, etc.
     */

    if (copy_to_user(buf, i, 1))
            {return -EINVAL;}
    /*
     * Tell the user how much data we wrote.
     */
    *ppos = len;

    return len;
    }
```

If someone could point out to me why this is happening I would greatly appreciate it. This was also taken from a hello world code, so the extra stuff is from that. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you didn't include linux/random.h:

```
#include <linux/random.h>
```